# Can't save files created with vim anymore

Tags: vim, text-editor

I usually am able to save my vim files but for some reason i am getting E212 can't open file for writing. I am using mac osx. I am confused on how to edit my .vimrc file, and that there are two? one for the system and one for user.

Comment: This question needs more information. What file are you trying to edit?

Answer (score 1):

The one you are supposed to edit is either `~/.vimrc` (all Vim versions, including 7.4 and up) or `~/.vim/vimrc` (only 7.4 and up).

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198898/what-is-the-difference-between-exrc-and-vimrc) give a detail introduction about vi/vim configuration file, you can read it to find what you need.